# Cypress - checking for the presence of a button and clicking on it if it is there

Tags: javascript, css, conditional-statements, cypress, visibility

Using Cypress I am testing a product which includes an autosave feature which kicks in at regular intervals. You can't guarantee when exactly the autosave will trigger as it is dependent on a number of factors. It also has a manual save option, clicking on a button #saveIcon which is only present before the autosave runs and is hidden after (until another change requires saving).

I would like to interrogate the page and if the `#saveIcon` is visible, click on it, but if it it isn't then click on something else. When it's not visible it appears to have the CSS property `visibility: hidden`.

With the saveIcon forced to be hidden, I tried this:

```
          cy.get('#saveIcon')
            .then($button => {
                if ($button.is(':visible')) {
                    cy.wrap($button).click()
                } else {
                    cy.get('.otherButton').click()
                }
            })
```

I expected the .otherButton to be clicked but it's trying to click the $button (to complete the IF part) instead, timing out on the click() because the icon is not visible. I guess the button is visible to Cypress but not to me.

I tried switching the question round, to test if it has the CSS property `visibility: hidden` and clicking on the ELSE option, but can't work out the syntax.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you tried - `if( Cypress.dom.isVisible($button) )` option ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery click,

```js
cy.get('#saveIcon')
  .then($button => {
    if ($button.is(':visible')) {
      $button.click()
    } else {
      cy.get('.otherButton').click()
    }
  })
```

but you are always going to click the `#saveIcon` button and not `.otherButton` because the if statement is always going to be faster than the autosave can finish and hide the `#saveIcon` button.

You should explicitly wait for `#saveIcon` to be hidden, then click the other button.

```js
cy.get('#saveIcon:hidden')
cy.get('.otherButton').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is visible to jQuery (`$button.is(':visible') === true`) but not to Cypress (`cy.wrap($button).click() // fails`), then it's possible that the force option will make it work.

See [click()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Arguments), there may be other [actionability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Actionability) factors preventing the click.

```js
cy.get('#saveIcon')
  .then($button => {
    if ($button.is(':visible')) {
      cy.wrap($button).click({ force: true })   // ignore actionability checks
    } else {
      cy.get('.otherButton').click()
    }
 })
```

---

If the auto-save can be predictably triggered (e.g entering some data), a test for each branch will give you greater code coverage.

If the auto-save interval is not predictable, increase the timeouts.

**before auto-save occurs**

```js
it('shows manual save button after form is made dirty', () => {
  cy.get('input').type('change-the-value')     // make form dirty
  cy.get('#saveIcon', { timeout: 5_000 })
    .should('be.visible')                      // button is present within 5 seconds
})
```

**after auto-save occurs**

```js
it('hides manual save button after auto-save', () => {
  cy.get('input').type('change-the-value')     // make form dirty
  cy.get('#saveIcon', { timeout: 5_000 })
    .should('be.visible')                      // button is present within 5 seconds
  cy.get('#saveIcon', { timeout: 5_000 })
    .should('not.be.visible')                  // auto-save ran, button is not present 
})
```

---

If the auto-save is unpredictable (say occurs save 3 out of 5 times), you can add a test retry option to repeat the test up 5 times, or until it passes

```js
it('hides manual save button after auto-save', { retries: 5 }, () => {
```

Comment: Hi @E Q, thanks so much for your response. In the test above I've made sure that the saveIcon is not user-visible in advance so I'm not expecting the $button to be clicked at all - the condition present means the ELSE part of the statement should be actioned ('.otherButton').

My use of :visible may be the problem, but if the button exists somewhere but is in some way hidden at the same time I'm not sure how to check for it and get the answer I'm looking for!

Comment: So, the #saveIcon button always has `visibility: hidden`?

Comment: Hi, no - it only has that status when the autosave has already run. When scriptIsDirty, the icon is visible to the user and there don't appear to be any visibility styles associated with it. After the autosave has run, the script is considered clean and the icon disappears from view with `.not-visible {visibility: hidden}` seen in dev tools.

Comment: I wonder if the way round this is to test for `visibility: hidden` and IF found, click on .otherButton, ELSE click on saveIcon, however this also doesn't seem to work, again it doesn't seem to recognise the button as `if ($button.is(':hidden')) {` and tries to invoke the ELSE action!

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought - the visibility of the button corresponds to the autosave cycle and scriptIsDirty. So what preceeds the code you have? Are you triggering scriptIsDirty in some manner? `$button.is(':visible')` and/or `$button.is(':hidden')` are going to be evaluated really fast, but `.should('be.visible')` and `.should('not.be.visible')` are going to retry for whatever timeout you set.

Comment: Preceding this is some material added via `.type('some text in here')` which reveals the saveIcon. Before proceeding to the next test I wish to make sure the material is saved. If Autosave has kicked in then great, but if not I need to click that saveIcon before going any further, hence trying the if/else. That it's visible or not (the .should assertion) is useful but clicking on it if it's there is the endgame. Cheers